# Sorting NSArray by file creation time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've read all answers about the subject, but still have my array unsorted. Please, help me with this issue. What's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filename error:NULL];
NSDate *date = [attributes fileCreationDate];
NSMutableArray *datesList  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[datesList addObject:date];
NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
sortedArray = [datesList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    if ([obj1 date] > [obj2 date]) 
    {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    if ([obj1 date] < [obj2 date]) 
    {
       return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
NSLog(@"sortedarray:%@",sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you add to the array only one object :)

Your code should look like:

```
sortedArray = [datesList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate *first, NSDate *second){
   return [first compare:second];
}];
```

`[NSDate compare:]` returns `` `NSComparisonResult `` which is fine. You can add `!` if you want to have opposite sorting direction.

Comment: thanks for the reply! i'm running this code within a loop:
  int savesamount = [savesdirectory count];
        for (int i = 0; i<savesamount; i++) { ... }.
still getting unsorted data:
  sortedarray:("2013-10-21 12:52:26 +0000")
  sortedarray:("2013-10-21 12:52:10 +0000")
  sortedarray:("2013-10-21 12:52:00 +0000")
  sortedarray:("2013-10-21 12:52:05 +0000")
  sortedarray:("2013-10-21 12:52:21 +0000")
  sortedarray:("2013-10-21 12:52:15 +0000")
  sortedarray:("2013-10-21 12:51:49 +0000")

but is that correct to compare objects within the loop too?